# Can Jest testing framework test the code written in java as TS calls a java function

Tags: javascript, typescript, binding, jestjs

My project is on Java-JS/TS, I am currently writing test cases for JS/TS in jest. One module is calling Java function and returns a value to Js based on which test will pass or fail. My question is will jest run this test as it involves Java code? If no then How can I test the module?
Pls advise.